# How to split a string after specific character in SQL Server and update this value to specific column

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-update

I have table with data `1/1` to `1/20` in one column. I want the value 1 to 20 i.e value after '/'(front slash) is updated into other column in same table in SQL Server.

***Example:***

Column has value `1/1,1/2,1/3...1/20`
new Column value `1,2,3,..20`

That is, I want to update this new column.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Col2 = RIGHT(Col1,LEN(Col1)-CHARINDEX('/',Col1))
```

Comment: great idea to combine `charindex` with `right` - it also works with `left`, really cool :)

Comment: Just needed myself, and it works in DB2 too if you sub `LEN` with `LENGTH` and `CHARINDEX` with `LOCATE`

Comment: It helped finding number in string after space `@declare s varchar(10) , REPLACE(RIGHT(string,LEN(@)-CHARINDEX(' ',@s)),' ','')`

Answer (score 15):

Please find the below query also split the string with delimeter.

```
Select Substring(@String1,0,CharIndex(@delimeter,@String1))
```

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-536.aspx

To use function LEFT if not all data is in the form '1/12' you need this in the second line above:

```
Set Col2 = LEFT(Col1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', Col1) - 1, -1), LEN(Col1)))
```

Comment: I guess some one didn't understand what I meant.
Your data:
1/1;
1/2;
2/1;
2/2;
2/3;
3;
4/1;
You might have an error in "3" due to the missing sub-part.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ParentBGBU,0,CHARINDEX('-',ParentBGBU,0)) FROM dbo.tblHCMMaster;
```

Comment: may be not usefull for this question but this answer save my 1 hrs of googling. its giving me my expected result as `A5/LS/CHMB/17-18/WAI` will be `A5`

Comment: thanx.i got my solution using this

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is specific to sql server, but I'm using postgresql and came across this question, so for anybody else in a similar situation, there is the `split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)` function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Column1 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT '1/1' UNION ALL
SELECT '1/20' UNION ALL
SELECT '1/2'
```

Then like this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(tbl.Column1,CHARINDEX('/',tbl.Column1)+1,LEN(tbl.Column1))
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT emp.LoginID, emp.JobTitle, emp.BirthDate, emp.ModifiedDate  , 
      CASE  WHEN emp.JobTitle  NOT LIKE '%Document Control%'  THEN emp.JobTitle
            ELSE SUBSTRING(emp.JobTitle,CHARINDEX('Document Control',emp.JobTitle),LEN('Document Control'))
      END 
      ,emp.gender,emp.MaritalStatus
FROM   HumanResources.Employee [emp]
WHERE  JobTitle LIKE '[C-F]%'
```

Comment: Code-only post are discourage here. Perhaps you should include an explanation.

Comment: no explaination? and use of unrelated column names!

Answer (score -1):

Use `CHARINDEX`. Perhaps make user function. If you use this split often. 
 
I would create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String VARCHAR(max),
    @Delimiter varCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'INT_COLUMN' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'STRING_COLUMN' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Your answer is vague.