# Loop through table records and update from another table records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `tblAddress [(Address nvarchar(500),District nvarchar(50)]` and `tblDisrtict [(District nvarhchar(50)]`.

Some sample data:

**tblAddress:**

```
HON MANI # no St.Chom Chao Trapeang Thloeng Chaom Chau Dangkao  N/A
CHENG HORN # 18 St 12 Tuek L'ak Muoy Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh   N/A
KHANG HONG # 9 St 50 Boeng Kak Muoy Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh    N/A
SANG MOY #10A St.no Kakab Dangkao Phnom Penh    N/A
NONG NAT #815 St No Stueng Mean Chey Mean Chey Phnom Penh   N/A
CHEA MONG #No St lum Phnom Penh Thmei Phnom Penh Thmei Ruessei Kaev     N/A
SOM KOY # 2E st 16 Phum5 Phsar Kandal Muoy Doun Penh Phnom Penh N/A
LE VANLYDA # 32 st 7 Kdei Chas Bak Khaeng Russei Keo Phnom Penh N/A
LAY NA # 35 st 70 Phum10 Boeng Salang Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh  N/A
```

**tblDistrict:**

```
Chamkar Mon
Doun Penh
Prampir Meakkakra
Tuol Kouk
Dangkao
Mean Chey
Russey Keo
Saensokh
Pur SenChey
Chraoy Chongvar
Praek Pnov
Chbar Ampov
```

I'd like to have the result as below

1. delete Name (capital letter) from Address
2. Update tblAddress column: District (N/A) with column: Address content district from tblDistrict.

   ```
   UPDATE tblAddress 
   SET District = @district 
   WHERE '%' + Address + '%' = @district
   ```

   but I don't know how to loop through `tblDistrict` to pass data to `@district`.

Any help please.

Comment: Is this a one time deal or a reoccurring requirement?

Comment: @Erik Philips this is just one time deal, and data is more than 100K.

Comment: Can you explain how `tblDistrict` linked to `tblAddress`?

Comment: This might help: [SQL update query using joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins)

Comment: @har07 tblDistrict is referenced to tblAddress, the Address column content district word. thay why i'd to update column District in tblAddress with data from tblDistrict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the relation between the two tables correctly, you can achieve that better using `JOIN` instead of looping :

```
UPDATE
    tblAddress
SET
    District = B.District
FROM
    tblAddress A
    JOIN
    tblDistrict B ON A.Address LIKE '%' + B.District + '%'
WHERE
    A.District = 'N/A'
```

Comment: thanks. btw. how to remove Name (capital letter) from Address?

Comment: how about update the column with the result of [substring after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260044/how-to-split-a-string-after-specific-character-in-sql-server-and-update-this-val) character `#`

Comment: the Name is specified by all capital letter, some doesn't has # sign for sub-string. so any way to find double capital?