# SQL UPDATE specific characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with the following values (there is alot more):

```
20150223-001
20150224-002
20150225-003
```

I need to write an UPDATE statement which will change the first 2 characters after the dash to 'AB'. Result has to be the following:

```
 20150223-AB1
 20150224-AB2
 20150225-AB3
```

Could anyone assist me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it always be 8 characters before the dash? Then you can use substring and concat.

Comment: See if it can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260044/how-to-split-a-string-after-specific-character-in-sql-server-and-update-this-val

Comment: yes its always 8 charachters before the dash but the characters after the dash can vary. It has to update the first two after the dash.

Comment: If the input is `20150223-00001`, what is the expected Output ? `20150223-AB001`, or `20150223-ABCD1`, ??

Comment: What about values like `20170123-015` or `20170123-123`, do those also occur? And how should those be handled?

Answer (score 3):

Use this,

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(30) = '20150223-0000000001'

SELECT STUFF(@MyString,CHARINDEX('-',@MyString)+1,2,'AB')
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is a lot of data, you could consider to use `.WRITE` clause. But it is limited to `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` data types.

If you have one of the following column types, the `.WRITE` clause is easiest for this purpose, example below:

```
UPDATE Codes
SET val.WRITE('AB',9,2)
GO
```

Other possible choice could be simple `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE Codes
SET val=REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,10,2),'AB')
GO
```

or `STUFF`:

```
UPDATE Codes
SET val=STUFF(val,10,2,'AB')
GO
```

I based on the information that there is always 8 characters of date and one dash after in the column. I prepered a table and checked some solutions which were mentioned here.

```
CREATE TABLE Codes(val NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO Codes
SELECT TOP 500000 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),GETDATE()-CHECKSUM(NEWID())%1000,112)+'-00'+CAST(ABS(CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%10000 AS INT)) AS NVARCHAR(128))
FROM sys.columns s1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns s2
```

I run some tests, and based on 10kk rows with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column, I got following results:

```
+---------+------------+
| Method  |    Time    |
+---------+------------+
| .WRITE  | 28 seconds |
| REPLACE | 30 seconds |
| STUFF   | 15 seconds |
+---------+------------+
```

As we can see `STUFF` looks like the best option for updating part of string. `.WRITE` should be consider when you insert or append new data into string, then you could take advantage of minimall logging if the database recovery model is set to bulk-logged or simple. According to MSDN articleabout `UPDATE` statement: [Updating Large Value Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql#LOBValues)

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
update table set column=stuff(column,charindex('-',column)+1,2,'AB')
```

Comment: it is not working if the input is `20150223-0000000001`, plz check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table1 TABLE (DateValue Varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT '20150223-000000001' Union all
SELECT '20150224-000000002' Union all
SELECT '20150225-000000003'

SELECT DateValue,
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(DateValue,0,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)),
REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(DateValue,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)+1,Len(DateValue)),2),'00','-AB'),
SUBSTRING(DateValue,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)+1,Len(DateValue))) AS ExpectedDateValue
FROM @Table1
```

OutPut

```
   DateValue                ExpectedDateValue
---------------------------------------------
   20150223-000000001   20150223-AB000000001
   20150224-000000002   20150224-AB000000002
   20150225-000000003   20150225-AB000000003
```

To Update

```
Update @Table1
SEt DateValue= CONCAT(SUBSTRING(DateValue,0,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)),
REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(DateValue,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)+1,Len(DateValue)),2),'00','-AB'),
SUBSTRING(DateValue,CHARINDEX('-',DateValue)+1,Len(DateValue)))
From @Table1

SELECT * from @Table1
```

OutPut

```
    DateValue
   -------------
20150223-AB000000001
20150224-AB000000002
20150225-AB000000003
```

Comment: It is not working if the input is `20150223-0000000001`, plz check my answer ?

Comment: Thanx i just chnage my code it works for above data also preceeding with more zero's

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP Comment:-

> Its always 8 charachters before the dash but the characters after the
>   dash can vary. It has to update the first two after the dash.

use the next simple code:-

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(30) = '20150223-0000000001'

SELECT REPLACE(@MyString,SUBSTRING(@MyString,9,3),'-AB')
```

Result:-

```
20150223-AB00000001
```

Comment: Risky if the same sequence of characters can also appear in other positions *as well*. This would replace all instances rather than just those appearing at positions 9-11.

Comment: You are right, in the end the code is created based on OP requirements.